# Linked server query fails when using an Alias after a schema change

Tags: sql-server-2017, linked-server, alias

Recently we added a new column [NewColumn] in a table [OurTable]. After that, a query from linked server referencing this table failed with error:

> The multi-part identifier "[OurTable].[NewColumn]" could not be bound.

This is the query referencing the table, it was not even referencing the NewColumn.

```
SELECT 'test' AS dummy FROM [LinkedServer].[Database].[Schema].[OurTable] ot
```

The fix was to get rid of the alias and the query worked

```
SELECT 'test' AS dummy FROM [LinkedServer].[Database].[Schema].[Table]
```

The only change is removing the alias.

I'm lost here, I've checked `sp_serveroption` for `lazy schema validation` and it's `false`.

I wanted to try to create a synonym, but I'm missing the permissions to do so.

EDIT: Found the same problem [here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/query-on-linked-server-fails-when-using-a-table-alias-help)

Comment: What edition are you using? Lazy schema validation is an Enterprise feature.

Comment: I'm on a Enterprise edition.

Comment: Ok. Id suspect a meta data issue. Can you could drop and recreate the linked server?

Comment: When I added a column to a table on a linked server instance, and ran your query, it ran succesfully. Could you add some more details as to reproduce the error? Such as the permissions on the linked service login, what column was addded,...?